# Joining value from Context parameter to Line property from Select-String output

Tags: powershell, select-string

I'm trying to compile log errors from multiple files in a single directory. The error messages are included over the span of two lines. I would like to concatenate both lines into a single line/object and then export all errors into a a neat csv.

I'm attempting to accomplish this with the Select-String utility, and the -Context parameter. Prior to piping the results through the Select-Object utility, everything's Kosher. However, Once I pipe the results through Select-Object or Export-CSV, the -Context line is lost.

```
$trigger = 'ERROR'
$folderPath = 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\testpath'
$logFiles = gci -Path $folderPath -Filter *.txt -File
$logFiles | Select-String -Pattern $trigger -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch -Context 0,1 | Select-Object LineNumber, Line, Filename | 
Export-Csv -Path .\$(Get-Date -Format yyyymmddhhmmss).csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Omitting the Select-Object and Export-Csv Cmdlets yields the desired, raw, results with the friendly right angle bracket '>' (ASCII 62). The raw results can even be exported via the Out-File Cmdlet, no problem.

However, what I would like to do, is combine the Pattern line with the Context line, creating a single object, which would eventually be output as a csv for further analysis.

I would like apologize if this question seems trivial. I've scoured resources trying to figure this out and unfortunately haven't been able to. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe select-string through fl * to see what the properties are.

```
$a = ls log | select-string error -context 0,1                                                                                           
$a | fl *

IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 2
Line       : error
Filename   : log
Path       : /Users/js/log
Pattern    : error
Context    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext
Matches    : {0}

$a.context       

PreContext PostContext DisplayPreContext DisplayPostContext
---------- ----------- ----------------- ------------------
{}         {after }    {}                {after }
```

This worked for me:

```
ls log | select-string error -context 0,1 | select linenumber, line,          
  @{n='PostContext'; e={$_.context.postcontext}}, filename

LineNumber Line  PostContext Filename
---------- ----  ----------- --------
         2 error after       log
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works! I hate to take more of your time, but do you mind explaining to me the syntax behind what was done there '@{n='PostContext'; e={$_.context.postcontext}}'. Just for my own knowledge. Maybe even just pointing me in the right direction where I can read a little more about it, so I don't have to bother fine people like you in the future =D.

Comment: It's a calculated property for select-object.  It's very common.  You supply a hash table with a name and an expression.  See example 10 in the select-object help:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again @js2010